# Capistrano 3 and Mercurial, Cannot load such file -- capistrano/mercurial.rb

Tags: mercurial, capistrano, capistrano3

I get this error when trying to deploy with capistrano 3.

```
cap production deploy:setup
cap aborted!
cannot load such file -- capistrano/mercurial.rb
```

my deploy:

```
...
set :branch, "default"
set :deploy_to, "/var/rails"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :scm, 'mercurial'
...
```

Do I need some kind of extension? The only I've found so far is [Capistrano-Mercurial-Ext](http://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano-mercurial-ext) but it didn't help.

Comment: Could you provide your Capfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Capistrano 3 sourcecode in GitHub the Mercurial SCM task is called 'hg':

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/hg.rake

So try changing the line:

set :scm, 'mercurial'

To be:

set :scm, :hg